# Google deep link launches play store instead of app

Tags: android, android-activity, view, google-play, deep-linking

Am creating a deep link which can be in either ways : 
1) domain://home/activityname
2) domain://view/activityname

**Working :** deeplink#1 works fine which opens the app with the given activityname

**Not Working :** deeplink#2 opens the app in the google play store with open and uninstall. When I click on open, app opens with the home activity but not the given activity.

The only difference between these two is "home" and "view" - all the deeplinks with "home" as scheme working fine whereas "view" always open google play store.

Comment: I found the solution for this. It is resolved now. The error is "android:path=blablabla" parameter which is defined in the <data> tag of manifest file. Am passing a incorrect path param in the deep link and hence android os is not able to resolve a match and hence it launches the play store with the given package name.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. It is resolved now. The error is "android:path=blablabla" parameter which is defined in the  tag of manifest file. Am passing a incorrect path param in the deep link and hence android os is not able to resolve a match and hence it launches the play store with the given package name.